# BackgroundWorker takes a lot of time at creation

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a software that control a production line in a factory. There is some barcode readers along the line. When the software receives a barcode, it must call a procedure in a Progress database. Sometimes, the call takes 1-2 seconds, so it's enclosed in a backgroundworker.

For an unknown reason, after a few hours running, the dynamic creation of the BGW takes a LOT of time. Can be between 5 seconds to 9 minutes!!!!

Here is the code for the BGW creation:

```
Dim oParams() As Object = {aParam, opCode, Barcode}
Dim bckInsert As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

AddHandler bckInsert.DoWork, AddressOf bckInsert_DoWork
MyBase.Add("Création background pour " & Barcode)
bckInsert.RunWorkerAsync(oParams)
```

`MyBase.Add` calls a function to log information to an ASCII file.

Here is the code of the `DoWork` Handler:

```
Private Sub bckInsert_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim oParams() As Object = e.Argument

    Try
        Dim aParam = CType(oParams(0), Progress.Open4GL.Proxy.ParamArray)
        Dim opCode As String = oParams(1).ToString
        Dim Barcode As String = oParams(2).ToString

        MyBase.Add("Début DoWork: " & Barcode & " Op: " & opCode)
```

Normally, the log lines should be consecutive in the file.

Now, here is an example of the log file:

```
11:00:04:243 - Création background pour 1580570 001000  
11:00:04:243 - Début DoWork: 1580570 001000 Op: 130
```

same time.

Now, when the creation takes ages:

```
11:00:37:049 - Création background pour 1580578 001000  
11:00:42:977 - Début DoWork: 1580578 001000 Op: 130
```

5 seconds delay!!!

```
11:01:30:121 - Création background pour L5315273 001000  
11:10:47:884 - Début DoWork: L5315273 001000 Op: 240
```

9 minutes!!!!!!!!!

CPU is between 1 and 9% and there's still LOT of available RAM.

Anyone has an idea how this can happen?

Comment: Do you store your workers anywhere, and do you `Dispose` them?

Comment: Is `MyBase.Add` designed for non-blocking multiple thread access?

Comment: No, there is no Dispose. Worker are created from a local variable, my guess was its ressources are disposed by the garbage collector once the DoWork procedure is done

Comment: MyBase.Add is not specifically designed for non-blocking thread. But the problem was already present before I added the log functionnality

Comment: It does not have anything to do with Dispose().  You'll need to use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to find out why threadpool threads are not completing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't execute the solution on my dev laptop. If I replace Workers by Parallel.Invoke, would it be better?

Comment: How about [**remote debugging**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx)? Otherwise try tasks, and if that doesn't work you _could_ (but it's not recommended) try using raw threads.

Comment: Also, are you sure the problem haven't got something to do with the `CType` conversion you are performing? What happens if you write a log entry before the `Try/Catch`?

Comment: @VisualVincent, thanks for the recommendation. I didn't knew about remote debugging. But there's a lot of industrial devices attached to the computer, serial and ethernet, it won't be possible in this scenario. Also, I didn't tried adding a log before the CType. I can try it out

Comment: I very much doubt it will help, but instead of `Dim oParams() As Object = {aParam, opCode, Barcode}` you could have a class (say, "bgwParameters") with properties corresponding to the items in that array and in the BGW you can `Dim oParams() As bgwParameters = DirectCast(e.Argument, bgwParameters)`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks, but I doubt the CType conversion is taking 9 minutes to execute, even if I replace it by a class, no?!

Comment: In addition to @AndrewMorton's comment you shouldn't put parentheses after the variable name in that case since it would make the variable an array (which `e.Argument` isn't). -- And to answer your comment: No, making it a class won't speed anything up. In this case its purpose is just to improve readability and simplify things for you.

Comment: It is not for certain that it is the `CType` conversion either, but I thought there is the possibility since you're converting into a custom class that we've got no idea what kind of steps it performs in order to convert (although 9 minutes is rather extreme).

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, well spotted, it should be `Dim params As bgwParameters = DirectCast(e.Argument, bgwParameters)` (i.e. dropping the "o" from the name too). Thank you.